# Can't figure out how to set SSL connection in Jedis with Spring 2.0+

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I'm trying to set up a Spring 2.1.2 application to use Jedis with SSL, and can't find any documentation that isn't for Spring 2.x+. My code is:

```
  @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
  private String redisHost;
  @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
  private Integer redisPort;
  @Value("#{environment.REDIS_PASSWORD}")
  private String redisPassword;

  @Bean
  JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {

    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration =
        new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);

    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(
        RedisPassword.of(redisPassword));

    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
  }
```

Anyone know what to do? I've tried adding `rediss://` to the front of redisHost, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install STunnel and implement it along side your Jedis(Redis) server. Easiest is the follow the Redis guide here:

https://redislabs.com/blog/stunnel-secure-redis-ssl/